# Postgres - split TSTZRANGE in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-range

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4
I have column in a table named `timerange` and want to write a `SELECT` query which will return time range in two separate columns `time_start` and `time_end`.
I tried to handle this like an array but it doesn't work:

```
select *, timerange[0] as t_start from schedules;
```

Current table:

```
| id |                    timerange                        |  
|----|-----------------------------------------------------|  
| 1  | ["2017-05-05 19:00:00+02","2017-05-05 21:00:00+02") |  
| 2  | ["2017-05-05 19:00:00+02","2017-05-05 21:00:00+02") |
```

Desired table:

```
| id |        time_start        |       time_end           | 
|----|--------------------------|--------------------------|
| 1  | "2017-05-05 19:00:00+02" | "2017-05-05 21:00:00+02" |  
| 2  | "2017-05-05 19:00:00+02" | "2017-05-05 21:00:00+02" |
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) `lower()` and `upper()`.

Like this:

```
SELECT lower(tsrng) AS start, upper(tsrng) AS end
FROM (
  SELECT tstzrange('2017-05-05 12:00:05', '2017-05-05 16:00:05', '[)') AS tsrng
) sub;
```

Or your example:

```
select *, lower(timerange) as t_start, upper(timerange) as t_end from schedules;
```

Comment: Works like a charm but I think the timezone is lost because from this timerange `["2017-05-05 14:00:00+02","2017-05-05 15:00:00+02")` I get `t_start` equal `2017-05-05 14:00:00.000000`

Comment: @veich [The time-zone information is there](http://rextester.com/VUCAL92330). Probably, your client interprets the response & puts it to your local time-zone.

Comment: IMO it's better to always save the timezone in the database in UTC