# How to convert PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone to Java Instant or OffSetDateTime?

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime, jdbc, timestamp-with-timezone

How to convert PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone to Java Instant or OffSetDateTime?

PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone format: `2020-06-18 16:15:38+05:30`

Getting the following exception in Java 11.7 - Ubuntu for `Instant.parse("2020-06-18 16:15:38+05:30".replace(" ", "T"))`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-06-18T16:15:38+05:30' could not be parsed at index 19
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
at java.base/java.time.Instant.parse(Instant.java:395)
at OffSetDateTimeExample.main(OffSetDateTimeExample.java:9)
```

but it works in Java 13.

Any help to make it work in Java 11

Comment: Don't parse it. Use `ResultSet.getObject(..., OffsetDateTime.class)`

Comment: Do what @a_horse_with_no_name suggested, but if you refuse to do it because you insist on a parsing solution, define a suitable pattern and parse the database column value to an `OffsetDateTime` by `OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-06-18 16:15:38+05:30", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssxxx"));`.

Comment: In the database, I have "tstzrange".

Comment: That's a range type, not a `timestamp with time zone`. Probably the easiest way to retrieve that is to use `select lower(..), upper(...)`  to get the two edges of the range as two separate columns. Then use `getObject(..., OffsetDateTime.class)` on each of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres - split TSTZRANGE in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806314/postgres-split-tstzrange-in-two-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Split the range type value

`tstzrange` is a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) in Postgres.

Split the PostgreSQL `tstzrange` in query by calling the `lower`  and `upper` functions.

```
select 
    *, 
    lower(tstzrange) as lower_tstzrange, 
    upper(tstzrange) as upper_tstzrange 
from announcement
;
```

and use it in `Resultset` as `OffsetDateTime`

```
TstzRange.builder()
    .startDateTime(rs.getObject("lower_tstzrange", OffsetDateTime.class))
    .endDateTime(rs.getObject("upper_tstzrange", OffsetDateTime.class))
            .build()
```

---

Thanks to [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) and [Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash) for saving my day & learnt splitting range datatypes.

Comment: Great, concise and informative answer. TIL. Thanks.

Comment: Spot on! Do not forget to accept it so that future visitors can also use the solution confidently.